# HATEOAS - Get links for resources not associated with current controller

Tags: asp.net-core, hateoas

I have a simple WebApi app managing Gym visits - workouts, exercises, weights etc. Two entities of interest here are User (visitor) and Workout. UsersController and WorkoutsController are doing their typical CRUD operations and adding HATEOAS links to each resource in the response. On top of that UsersController can provide list of workouts for individual User via route "api/v1/Users/{id}/Workouts".

But now I am unable to generate links for Workouts because UsersController doesn't work with this entity and can generate links for Users only. I know that instantiating WorkoutsController directly is a bad practice, so I didn't try that. So my question is how to make it work without breaking REST? Is there an out-of-box solution or do I need my own implementation/workaround for this one?

Thanks.

[EDIT]
Code I'm using to generate links for resources:

```
public static class ResourceLinksGeneration
{
    public static List<Link> CreateLinksForResource(this LinkGenerator linkGenerator, 
        HttpContext context, 
        int resourceID, 
        Dictionary<string, string> methods)
    {
        return new List<Link>
        {
            new Link
            {
                HttpMethod = "GET",
                Description = "self",
                Url = linkGenerator.GetUriByAction(context, methods[nameof(DefaultApiConventions.Get)], values: new { id = resourceID } )
            },

            new Link
            {
                HttpMethod = "POST",
                Description = "add",
                Url = linkGenerator.GetUriByAction(context, methods[nameof(DefaultApiConventions.Post)])
            },

            new Link
            {
                HttpMethod = "PUT",
                Description = "update",
                Url = linkGenerator.GetUriByAction(context, methods[nameof(DefaultApiConventions.Put)])
            },

            new Link
            {
                HttpMethod = "DELETE",
                Description = "delete",
                Url = linkGenerator.GetUriByAction(context, methods[nameof(DefaultApiConventions.Delete)], values: new { id = resourceID })
            }
        };

    }
}
```

Comment: Is your workout logic inside your Workout controller or a bespoke repository or service class?

Comment: @Marco data fetching is in repository, controller is just calling repo and transforming result into DTO.

Comment: How do you retrieve the metadata for the resources? links et al (Show us the code)

Comment: @Marco added to original post.

Comment: Get confuse about how this generator not work. Can you show the usercontroller code?

Comment: @Jerry the problem is not in generator itself, it works fine inside each controller in isolation, but my goal is to generate links from one controller for the resources produced by another controller. HttpContext is a crucial parameter for this method and I can't have HttpContext of WorkoutController when http request is routed to UserController and vise versa.